# Populating a treeview with two tables using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, treeview

Hello I have this two tables:

[image]

[image: subDepartment table]

Then I want this result using treeview:

**id**     **department**      **category**

- 1              MIS           System 
  1             MIS            Networking 
  1   MIS          Programmer
- 2              Audit           Operations 
  2             Audit           DS
- 3              HRD             PA 
  3             HRD            PayBen 
  3
  HRD            PS 
  3             HRD             PLD
- 4              Acounting Sup 
  4              Acounting    FMCG
- 5               Procurement  NULL

or like this

- MIS

-System
   -Networking
   -Programmer

- AUDIT
  -Operations
  -DS
- HRD
  -PA
  -PayBen
  -PS
  -PLD
- Acounting
  -Sup
  -FMCG

Can someone please guide me, thank you. I'm having trouble finding any solution on the internet and I'm new to the vb.net language.

Answer (score 0):

In my code below, i give you the logic. You just need to query your tables now.

Tell me if you need explanations.

```
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

    'Create a first node and select it
    Dim root As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Test")
    TreeView1.SelectedNode = root

    'Create two types of node
    Dim department As New TreeNode()
    Dim category As New TreeNode()

    'Daos (if you create a Department class and subDepartment class)
    Dim _daoD As New Departments(_cnx)
    Dim _daoSD As New subDepartments(_cnx)

    'Lists (depending on classes too)
    Dim listD As List(Of Department)
    Dim listSD As List(Of subDepatment)

    For Each dep As Department In listD
        'Add a Tree node for a new department
        department = New TreeNode(dep.department)
        department.Tag = dep.id
        root.Nodes.Add(department)
        TreeView1.SelectedNode = departement

        For Each subDep As subDepartment In listSubDep
            'Add a TreeNode for new categories
            categ = New TreeNode(subDep.category)
            categ.Tag = subDep.id
            Nodes.Add(categ)
        Next
    Next
```

Then, you can create 4 classes (the first one with properties, and the second one to query in the table)

```
Public Class Department 
    'properties
        Public Property id As Integer
        Get
            Return _ID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            _ID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
   'etc
End Class

Public Class Departments
    Dim _cnx As OracleConnection (if you use Oracle)
    Public Sub New(ByVal pcnx As OracleConnection)
        _cnx = pcnx
    End Sub

   'Your queries
End Class
```

Comment: Hello nbadaud, thank you for your quick response, im using vb.net 2008 which is the code you give me is not applicable. like for example ".tag" or having two public class. and also yes i need little explanation of the code. hoping for your reply. thank you so much.

Comment: somehow kind of i dont get the whole code, but fortunately i solved it. thank you again.

Comment: you could post your solution then

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solutio. i hope this will help someone who have this kind of problem.

Dim myConnString As String = "Data Source=name;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim daMyName As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dsMyName As New DataSet
        Dim recCount As Integer
        Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT DEPARTMENT.department, subDept.category from subdept right join department on .department.id = subDept.parent"
        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnString)
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
        myConnection.Open()
        daMyName.SelectCommand = myCommand
        daMyName.Fill(dsMyName)
        Dim tbl As DataTable = dsMyName.Tables(0)
        recCount = dsMyName.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        tvw1.Nodes.Clear()  'Clear any nodes so we don't load a tree into a tree

```
    Dim nd As TreeNode
    nd = tvw1.Nodes.Add("DEPARTMENT")
    Dim parentRow As DataRow

    Dim rowNdx As Integer
    rowNdx = 0
    daMyName.Fill(tbl)
    Dim Jan As String
    For Each parentRow In tbl.Rows
        If rowNdx = recCount Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Jan = dsMyName.Tables(0).Rows(rowNdx)("Department").ToString() 'set the next name
        Dim Dnode As TreeNode
        Dnode = tvw1.Nodes.Add(dsMyName.Tables(0).Rows(rowNdx)("department").ToString())
        Dim cnode As TreeNode
        cnode = New TreeNode
        Do While dsMyName.Tables(0).Rows(rowNdx)("department").ToString() = Jan And rowNdx < recCount
            'if it changes we need to kick out of Do While
            cnode = Dnode.Nodes.Add(dsMyName.Tables(0).Rows(rowNdx)("category").ToString())
            rowNdx = rowNdx + 1
            If rowNdx = recCount Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Next parentRow
    myConnection.Close()
```